# ¿Porqué las letras de un string se asignan así en los bucles?

Tags: python

mi duda es la siguiente, este es el codigo:

```
print("Verificación de correos")
def listaCorreos():
    correo=[]
    condicion=""
    while True:
        correo.append(input("Introduce correo electrónico: "))
        condicion=input("Pulse 1 para salir enter para continuar.")
        if condicion=="1":
            break
    return correo

def comprobar(correo):
    listaComprobada=[]
    for i in correo:
        contadorArro=0
        contadorPunto=0
        for j in i:
            if j=="@":
                contadorArro+=1
            if j=="." and contadorArro==1:
                contadorPunto+=1
        if contadorArro==1 and contadorPunto==1:
            listaComprobada+=[i]
    return listaComprobada
```

Basicamente te permite crear una lista de correos y despues te verifica que estos estan bien, la duda me surje en la siguiente línea de la función `comprobar()`:

```
listaComprobada+=[i]
```

¿Porqué la variable `listaComprobada` si la pongo asi  me crea la lista como yo quiero y si lo hago asi

```
listaComprobada+=i
```

me asigna en cada posición la letra de los correos que pasan?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: porque `listaComprobada` es un lista o arreglo y  `listaComprobada+=i` es igual a `listaComprobada.append(i)` mientras que `listaComprobada+=[i]` es como un group `i` or `''.join(i)` que luego hace un append a `listaComprobada`

Comment: @Bryro No es correcto este comentario. `lista+=i` es igual a `lista.extend(i)` y por eso no se comporta como el OP esperaba.Si fuera equivalente a `lista.append(i)` como dices habría funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintaxis `lista += elementos` es en el fondo una forma de invocar:

```
lista.extend(elementos)
```

y esta forma a su vez espera que `elementos` sea un tipo por el que se pueda iterar, y que contenga la serie de elementos que queremos añadirle a `lista`.

Por ejemplo, si `lista = [1,2]` y queremos añadirle los elementos `3` y `4`, podríamos hacer:

```
lista.extend([3,4])
```

o, lo que es equivalente, `lista += [3,4]`. En ambos casos el resultado sería que `lista` pasaría a tener `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Esto no es lo mismo que `lista.append(elemento)` que espera un solo elemento y lo añade al final de la lista.

Usando el mismo ejemplo de antes:

```
lista = [1, 2]
lista.append([3,4])
```

ahora el resultado sería que `lista` vale `[1, 2, [3,4]]`, pues en este caso la lista `[3,4]` se trata como *un solo elemento* para añadirle a `lista`.

Esto que he dicho sobre listas, se aplica a cadenas. Observa la diferencia:

```
lista = ["Hola", "mundo"]
lista.append("que")
lista.extend("tal")
```

El `.append()` añade a la `lista` un nuevo elemento, la cadena `"que"`, en cambio el `.extend()` añade una serie de elementos nuevos, los que obtenga al iterar por su argumento, que en este caso es una cadena. Al iterar por una cadena obtienes sus letras individuales. Por tanto al final la lista valdrá:

```
["Hola", "mundo", "que", "t", "a", "l"]
```

Y como hemos dicho `lista.extend("tal")` y `lista += "tal"` son lo mismo, lo que explica tu duda. Y eso explica también por qué `lista += ["tal"]` sí funciona como esperas, porque en ese caso es equivalente a `lista.extend(["tal"])`, y el argumento que le pasas a `extend` es una lista por la que itera para obtener los elementos a añadir, y en este caso encuentra sólo uno que es la cadena `"tal"`.

Como moraleja, yo diría que deberías usar `listaComprobada.append(i)` que es mucho más claro que `listaComprobada += [i]`

### Otras mejoras

- Elegir buenos nombres de variables ayuda mucho a leer el programa y entender lo que hace. El parámetro `correo` debería llamarse `correos` (pues es una lista de ellos). La variable `i` debería llamarse `correo` (pues es lo que contiene),  la variable `j` debería llamarse `caracter`.
- No necesitas implementar la cuenta de arrobas y puntos. Las cadenas python tienen el método `count()`

Mi propuesta es por tanto:

```
def comprobar(correos):
    listaComprobada=[]
    for correo in correos:
        if correo.count("@") == 1 and correo.count(".") == 1:
            listaComprobada.append(correo)
    return listaComprobada
```

o, si eres aficionado a los "*one-liners*", usando una comprensión de listas:

```
def comprobar(correos):
    return [correo for correo in correos if correo.count("@") == correo.count(".") == 1]
```

Comment: Okey lo pillo, muchas gracias por tu paciencia y tiempo.